# Placing Textview on ImageView Compatible on each screensize

Tags: android, textview, imageview

I have 2 images and 4 textviews and I want to place textviews on images my current work is like that.

I have to place 4 textview like 2. Image. Is there any way to make it without using DP because if i use DP when resolution changed looks  terrible.

My current work is:

[image: Current Work]

I want it to look like this:

[image: I want to make it like that.]

**My Activity Code**t

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:background="@color/grey"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="300dp">
      <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="horizontal">
         <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
             android:layout_width="0dp"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">


          <ImageView
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:src="@drawable/solayak"
              />
             <TextView
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:text="Deneme"
                 android:gravity=  "center"

                 />
         </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

          <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

          <ImageView
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:src="@drawable/sagayak"
              />
          </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
      </LinearLayout>



  </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/arti_buton_yeni" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/eksibutton_yeni" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <include
        layout="@layout/bottomnavigation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I recommend using ConstraintLayout or for faster result, use design mode

Comment: Okey i can use it but how can i do it in ConstraintLayout

Comment: @ShowYoungSoyinka Do you have a solution for this?

Comment: If you use design mode by drag and drop, ConstraintLayout will automatically be used

Comment: You dont understdant what i mean. I know it can be but it USES DP if i use dp its going to be changed on each device because each device and resolution have diffrent dps @ShowYoungSoyinka